# Delete JSON data via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot for a server with a few friends - I have a warn system and level system.
I've managed to get the JavaScript to write to the external JSON file.

```json
{
    "other-users": "other-user-data",

    "304937039483493847": {
        "amount": 1,
        "id": "<@304937039483493847>",
        "username": "Jered",
        "reasons": {
            "first-reason": "test"
        }
    },

    "other-users": "other-user-data"
}
```

I've managed to get the data to change from warnings to remove warnings, but I need to delete the whole `304937039483493847` object from the file.

What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it is what you need.

```js
let data = {
    "304937039483493847": {
    "amount": 1,
    "id": "<@304937039483493847>",
    "username": "Jered",
    "reasons": {
      "first-reason": "test"
    }
  },

  "other-users":"other-user-data"
};
console.log(data);
delete data["304937039483493847"];
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you, of course!
Took a bit of a break to fix something else.
This worked perfectly - 
For anyone who finds this later, I used what was here and the just wrote it to the JSON file :)